# Реализация блока с выбором точки фотографии

Tags: android, распознавание-символов, java

Делаю аналог приложения [OCR Test](https://market.android.com/details?id=edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImVkdS5zZnN1LmNzLm9yYW5nZS5vY3IiXQ).

Требуется реализовать блок с выбором места фотографии

[image: снимок]

Также видно на видео, как он работает. Т.е мы фотографируем ту часть, что в этом блоке, + можем тянуть его за концы и увеличивать или сужать. Пока я так и не понял, как его реализовать? Может кто-то что-то подскажет или ткнет на гайд с реализацией подобного графического элемента?

Answer (score 2):

Пример с реализацией View для выбора участка изображения при работе с камерой в Android есть [в этой статье](http://findevelop.blogspot.com/2012/05/android.html).